# Click the mouse when specific key pressed in C

Tags: c, windows, click, mouse

I've recently started college at Digipen, and have developed carpal tunnel already from all the writing/coding/etc... but fortunately for me, I'm learning to be a programmer, and have already made a few programs to assist with things like opening command prompt/bat files faster/without clicking, etc.

Since clicking the mouse is significantly more difficult for me than typing, I was wanting to make a simple program that would just run in the background, and click the mouse for me any time I press a specific key on the keyboard. I don't really know where to start with this though, and have never used anything but standard c so far. Also, being able to move the mouse with keypresses would be handy at times as well.

Thanks for the help. :)

Oh, and I should probably mention that I will be using this on both windows vista and 7, and of course I'll be the only one using it.

Comment: `SendInput` and `SetWindowsHookEx` work, but AHK is much faster than C.

Comment: This is just a general comment.  I would be extremely concerned about having developed this condition at all, and I would not be spending time at this point writing code.  Are you working to reverse this and balance your body?  These problems stem from poor posture, which comes from lack of core strength and/or poor working conditions.  I've been through it myself (although not to the point of being diagnosed with carpal tunnel).  You simply must turn this around.  Invasive 'treatments' like surgery do not address the root cause.

Comment: @OP, Seriously, AutoHotKey is perfect for this. It's a bad shortcut key, but to make it so whenever you press ctrl+C, it left clicks once at the cursor's current position, the AHK script is `^C::Click`. Change the shortcut to whatever you want and there you go!

Comment: @paddy I wear a wrist brace at all times, and have special gel mousepad. The school has provided a note taker for all of my classes, and I have stopped gaming altogether for the time being. I'm doing my best to take care of it.

Comment: @LemonyLime That's good to know.  What I meant is that you can quite possibly treat this condition rather than simply live with it.  I got through my own with physiotherapy, deep tissue massage, core-strengthening exercises, a lot of stretching and better nutrition.  The real problem wasn't my arms at all - it was my whole body.  I continue with core exercises and also swim in my lunch hour to maintain upper body strength for posture.  When your body can support its own frame correctly, you do not end up using the wrong muscles to compensate, and you are far less likely to sustain injury.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to find mouse cursor position (in screen coordinates) using **GetCursorPos(&p)**.  Then you can find the window under your mouse cursor using **WindowFromPoint(...)**. And then you can use **SendMessage(...)** to send "mouse down" and "mouse up" messages to that window... And here is a good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264/KeyBoard-Hooks) about hooking keyboard events in Windows.

Comment: Imo, that's reinventing the wheel of `SendInput`.